# What does config inside ``super().__init__(config)`` actually do?

Tags: python, oop, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have the following code to create a custom model for Named-entity-recognition. Using ChatGPT and Copilot, I've commented it to understand its functionality.

However, the point with `config` inside `super().__init__(config)` is not clear for me. Which role does it play since we have already used `XLMRobertaConfig` at the beginning?

```py
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import XLMRobertaConfig
from transformers.modeling_outputs import TokenClassifierOutput
from transformers.models.roberta.modeling_roberta import RobertaModel
from transformers.models.roberta.modeling_roberta import RobertaPreTrainedModel

# Create a class for a custom model, which inherit from RobertaPreTrainedModel since we want to use the weights of a pretained model in the body of a custom model
class XLMRobertaForTokenClassification(RobertaPreTrainedModel):
    # Common practice in  Transformers 
    # allows the XLMRobertaForTokenClassification class to inherit the configuration functionality and attributes from the XLMRobertaConfig class
    config_class = XLMRobertaConfig

    # initialize the model
    def __init__(self, config):
        # call the initialization function of the parent class (RobertaPreTrainedModel)
        super().__init__(config)              # config is necessary when working with pretrained models to ensure the initialization with the correct configuration of parent class
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels   # number of classes to predict

        # Load model BODY
        self.roberta = RobertaModel(config, add_pooling_layer=False) # returns all hidden states not just [CLS]
        
        # Set up token CLASSIFICATION HEAD
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)             
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.num_labels) # linear transformation layer takes (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size) 
                                                                           # to produce output tensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, num_labels)
                                                                           # which can be interpreted as probability distribution over the labels for each token in the input sequence.
        
        # Load the pretrained weights for the model body and 
        # ... randomly initialize weights of token classification head
        self.init_weights()

    # define the forward pass
    def forward(self, input_ids=None, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None, 
                labels=None, **kwargs):
        # Feed the data through model BODY to get encoder representations
        outputs = self.roberta(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask,
                               token_type_ids=token_type_ids, **kwargs)
        
        # Apply classifier to encoder representation 
        sequence_output = self.dropout(outputs[0]) # apply dropout to the first element of output tensor, i.e., last_hidden_state
        logits = self.classifier(sequence_output)  # apply the linear transformation to get the logits (i.e., raw output of the model)
        # Calculate losses if labels are provided
        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1)) # apply cross entropy function on flattend logits and flattend labels
        # Return model output object
        return TokenClassifierOutput(loss=loss, logits=logits, 
                                     hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states, 
                                     attentions=outputs.attentions)
```

**EDIT**: I quote directly from the book I'm working on: *"`config_class`  ensures that the standard `XLMRobertaConfig` settings are used when initilize a new model"*. If I understand it correctly, could we change these defualt parameters by overwriting the default settings in the `config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `config_class` doesn't contain any configuration parameters. It only contains `XLMRobertaConfig`, which is a `class`(/!\ not an instance of that class)

I'm not sure how `RobertaPreTrainedModel` model works, but it seems that, when you initialise an instance of `XLMRobertaForTokenClassification`, you need to give it the actual contents of the configuration (maybe as dictionary?)

But the class attribute `config_class` doesn't know anything about the values set in the configuration

*Edit*: Taken from the code of `PreTrainedModel`, which `RobertaPreTrainedModel` inherits from:

> ```py
> if not isinstance(config, PretrainedConfig):
>    config_path = config if config is not None else pretrained_model_name_or_path
>    config, model_kwargs = cls.config_class.from_pretrained(
>        config_path,
>        cache_dir=cache_dir,
>        return_unused_kwargs=True,
>        force_download=force_download,
>        resume_download=resume_download,
>        proxies=proxies,
>        local_files_only=local_files_only,
>        use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
>        revision=revision,
>        subfolder=subfolder,
>        _from_auto=from_auto_class,
>        _from_pipeline=from_pipeline,
>        **kwargs,
>    )
> ```

(Taken from [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.26.1/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L962))
the class_config is used as a fallback, if no valid config is given, to instantiate a config with default values

Comment: I quote directly from the book I'm working on: *"`config_class`  ensures that the standard `XLMRobertaConfig` settings are used when initilize a new model"*. If I understand it correctly, could we change these defualt parameters by overwriting the default settings in the configuration?